# Reforming to gain extra rank in close combat

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

If I have a unit that is 10 models wide. And an enemy unit is attacking me in the front with only one monster size model on the very far left side of my unit, can I reform my unit to gain an extra rank?

Or do I still have to reform around the center?

My unit only had one rank at the start of close combat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can reform if:

- You win the round of combat
- Or if you lose combat, hold and pass an unmodified leadership test.

I believe there is a limit to how many columns you can adjust per turn (from memory I think it's 5) however there should be no problem going from 10 columns to 5.

Assuming your models are on 20mm bases this will give you 4 models from each rank in each rank attacking and a +1 rank bonus (until the monster kills another model at least!).

Where the rules begin to get a little vague is when you're "moving" your unit in the combat to get more attacks. It's best to agree with your opponent before you start moving models.

The rules are clear that can't reform out of combat - they're a little vague on reforming to get more attacks in (although bear in mind that this is what you're effectively doing when you add more ranks). In my opinion the simplest solution is to treat the centre of combat as the centre of the unit and reform around that.

Comment: The enemy unit is attacking my unit in the front. Not the flank.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry when you said the left I assumed you meant the left flank. Edited.

Comment: No problem. You still know the rulling?

Comment: @prolink007 Basically the same but you don't need to rotate too - edited

Comment: Even though reforming says to do it around the middle of the unit? Because it would not be the middle for me.

Comment: @prolink007 this is where the prescribed rules break down a little and you'll need to agree with your opponent. The rules are clear that can't reform out of combat - they're a little vague on reforming to get more attacks in. Bear in mind that this is what you're effectively doing when you add more ranks though. IMHO the simplest solution is to treat the centre of combat as the centre of the unit and reform around that.

Comment: @prolink007 questions like this are the bane of my game... they're all about "I'd like to do this... do you think it's legal?" if in doubt ask next time you're in store and post your own GW approved answer!

Comment: I have no gw stores close enough. Sadly.